# C++, How to reference Class methods in a Struct?

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I am trying to humbly port "FastLED + ESP8266 Web Server" by Jason Coon: https://github.com/jasoncoon/esp8266-fastled-webserver to ESPAsyncWebServer, with a few extra goodies...

My project is located here https://github.com/kelexel/esp8266-fastled-async-webserver-2.0/

My main work on this project is to wrap everything into nice Classes, and try to afford some kind of modularity.

## EDIT: As many pointed out in the comments bellow, what I try to accomplish is clearly wrongly illustrated. All I am looking for are ideas, code sample, docs, references, on what should be done, so I can learn and improve...

I am totally new to C++, so please, be indulgent..

What I am trying to accomplish is obtain what I, neophyte, can only explain as a collection of objects, each objects having a String *name* and method *pattern*. Said *pattern* should be a method of the ESPLedDriver.cpp Class

The issue resides in the fact that in ESPLedDriver.h and ESPLedDriver.cpp, I try to create a Struct that references ESPLedDriver::

I made a snippet of the code to illustrate the issue:

ESPLedDriver.cpp

```
void ESPLedDriver::colorwaves()
{
  // ...
}
void ESPLedDriver::palettetest()
{
  // ...
}

void ESPLedDriver::setPatterns()
{
  // const uint8_t patternCount;
  _patterns = {

    // ERROR: src/ESPLedDriver.cpp:225:3: error: cannot convert 'ESPLedDriver::colorwaves' from type 'void (ESPLedDriver::)()' to type 'ESPLedDriver::Pattern {aka void (*)()}'
    { colorwaves, "Color Waves" },

    // ERROR: src/ESPLedDriver.cpp:225:3: error: cannot convert 'ESPLedDriver::palettetest' from type 'void (ESPLedDriver::)()' to type 'ESPLedDriver::Pattern {aka void (*)()}'
    { this->palettetest, "Palette Test" },
  };
}
```

ESPLedDriver.h

```
#include "FastLED.h"

  class ESPLedDriver
  {
  public:
    ESPLedDriver();
    // ...
  private:
    void setPatterns();
    typedef void (*Pattern)();
    typedef Pattern PatternList[];
    typedef struct {
      Pattern pattern;
      String name;
    } PatternAndName;
    typedef PatternAndName PatternAndNameList[];

    /* Patterns */
    void colorwaves();
    void palettetest();

    PatternAndNameList _patterns;
    uint8_t _patternCount;
}
```

(Or if you prefer, as a gist: 
https://gist.github.com/kelexel/ab5687cf83e376c709e49fbfbcfc100b )

Comment: C, C#, C++ are not the same. You should decide on one of them before you start writing code...

Comment: Why use function pointers instead of inheriting an abstract interface?

Comment: A pointer-to-member is not a "regular" pointer.

Comment: @user2393256: Of course you are right. I am starting to learn the differences. I am aware that my current code is probably giberish to you :/

Comment: You can be new to "C, C#, C++", but I am sure you are not new to the fact that similar names do not imply similarities.

Comment: I honestly do not know how to handle this situation properly, if you have any code example, that would really help ..

Comment: The title makes no sense. The post does not contain any question. It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @NickyC of course .. I never tried to imply any different ... If my post made you feel so, please forgive me.

Comment: @NickyC I edited the post, I hope this clarifies a bit...

Comment: @rud: I think I see your problem. In C++ there's a difference between function pointers and member function pointers. Your `Pattern` typedef should look  like `typdef void (ESPLedDriver::* pattern)();`

Comment: Your issue is that, according to the title, the C language does not have classes.   You can emulate classes in C, it will be a lot of work.

Comment: BTW, in C++ you don't need to use `typedef` with your structures.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Oh! I forgot to correct the title, now I understand the .. "confusion" I created :/
Duely noted about `typedef`

Answer (score 2):

If all of the objects are string and pattern, you can model them as an abstract base class:

```
class String_Pattern
{
  public:  
    virtual void pattern_method(ESPLedDriver& driver_to_use) = 0;
  private:
    std::string  text;
};
```

Note that this design requires passing the driver to the string pattern object.  Think of this giving the object a driver to use.

Comment: Oh yes, I understand what you mean !
But than, how may I "feed" them to the defined `PatternAndName patterns` struct (assuming a struct is still the best way to group all the abstract classes), so that I can later do something like `patterns[currentPatternIndex].pattern_method();` ..?